# Scraping using a nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to scrape information for an on project from the Oil and Gas Authority Open data site but my code returns no data

(The website I'm trying to scrape from)
http://data-ogauthority.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/ab4f6b9519794522aa6ffa6c31617bf8_0?uiTab=table

I have also realized that the site has an API but I do not know how to call an API in rails. If anybody can assist it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you give us your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get those data using requests module:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://data-ogauthority.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/ab4f6b9519794522aa6ffa6c31617bf8_0.geojson'
r = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(r.text)
# here you have the data loaded into a dict
```